# Opencv program doesn't work in release mode

Tags: c++, opencv, release

I have a program in which i'm trying to see if the image is white or not it works in debug mode but in release it doesn't work

```
   int image_blanche(char * str, double prctage){
       Mat img=imread(str);
       int compt=0;
       for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<img.cols;j++){
                if (img.at<uchar>(i,j)==0){
                compt=compt+1;
               }
           }
        }

        if (compt< img.rows*img.cols*prctage)
        {   
            return 1;
        }
       else if (compt> img.rows*img.cols*prctage){
            return 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the error message or the expected behavior of this code.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the function return the wrong value? Are you sure you're using the same image for both modes?

Comment: don't link release build against debug libs ;)

Comment: And make sure you are using the correct dlls if this is on windows. I mean vc12 for Visual Studio 2013. vc11 for Visual Studio 2012, vc10 for Visual Studio 2010, vc9 for Visual Studio 2008. And yes these are correct. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21730219/487892

Comment: Debug assertion failed

Comment: Which .lib entries did you choose in project settings?

Comment: i use lib without the d for example opencv_core247.lib but i notice a think that when i run the program it tells me that  somme debug dll is absent