# Missing MSVCP120D.dll but don't have Visual Studios anymore

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I dug up an old project of mine from college when we exclusively used Visual Studios, and I'm looking to run it again. I don't have the exe anymore, just the debug version.  When I run the debug version, I get the missing MSVCP120D.dll error.   I have no way to recompile this into the release version. Is there a way for me to download the missing dlls, without downloading Visual Studios?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707992/msvcp120d-dll-missing

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  I'm specifically trying to not use Visual Studios. That one discusses re-compiling as a release build.

Comment: Ok, I just googled and found this: http://www.telecharger-dll.fr/dll-msvcp120d.dll.html. I assume it's ok to download if you don't redistribute your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase you didn't know, MSVCP120D.dll is a dynamic link library for the IDE "Microsoft Visual C++ 12.0", which I believe is from Visual Studio 2013.

If you know the version of Visual Studio that you used (You specified 2010 and 2012 in the tags), you can use the following link  to download the toolchain, Visual C++: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2977003

Another option is reverse-engineering, but this will be an incredibly difficult process and cannot give you the source that you originally used to create the debug version. Your best bet is to find the version you're after, if not re-writing it.

This installation, should you have the administrator privileges to perform it, should cause the error to cease, as your system will be able to find it in Sys32/Syswow64.

Edit: I would be vary wary to download a .dll from any other site other than Microsoft's official site, malicious DLLs are readily available from dodgy sites.

Comment: The "D" indicates it's a Debug DLL which is not part of the standard REDIST. It's only present when you install the VS 2013 toolset.